# Apache HttpClient 3, multi threaded with different credential for each request?

Tags: java, httpclient

How to have specific credential for each request on HttpClient ? 
Problem what i have now is 2nd thread seems replace previous 1st thread credential.

Below is my sample code :

```
    class GetThread extends Thread {
    HttpClient httpClient;

    private String username,password;

    public GetThread(HttpClient httpClient,String username,String password) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
        this.username= username;
        this.password= password;
    }

    public void run() {

        Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        httpClient.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope("dummyhost", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM), defaultcreds);
        HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("http://dummyhost/RSL/servlets/dv.data");

        method.setDoAuthentication(true);
        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(method);

            byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+username+" "+new String(responseBody));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         finally {
             method.releaseConnection();
         }

    }
}
```

And this is what i put inside my main class :

```
    MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager connectionManager = 
        new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
    GetThread getThread[] = {new GetThread(httpClient, "rsbatch1", "test1234"),
            new GetThread(httpClient, "rsbatch12", "test1234")};

    for(int i=0;i<getThread.length;i++)
    {
        getThread[i].start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separate credentials per thread, then you need to have a separate client per thread also - each client has 1 set of credentials.

Change the contructor for GetThread to

```
public GetThread(HttpConnectionManager connectionManager,String username,String password) {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
    this.username= username;
    this.password= password;
}
```

and that should do what you need.